# Create a new value based on columns within groups in R

Tags: r

If the intervals between two dates within a group(bankAcctID) are the same, then create a new column diff between two dates; otherwise, create an `NA` value.

### Data

```r
structure(list(bankAcctID = c(439940L, 439940L, 439940L, 439940L, 439940L, 
439940L, 535211L, 535211L, 535211L, 535211L), date = structure(c(18334, 
18347, 18348, 18362, 18369, 18376, 18331, 18341, 18347, 18355 ), class = 
"Date")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), groups = structure(list(bankAcctID = c(439940L, 535211L), 
.rows = list(1:6, 7:10)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: here is the data> dput(predict[1:10,])
structure(list(bankAcctID = c(439940L, 439940L, 439940L, 439940L, 
439940L, 439940L, 535211L, 535211L, 535211L, 535211L), date = structure(c(18334, 
18347, 18348, 18362, 18369, 18376, 18331, 18341, 18347, 18355
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(bankAcctID = c(439940L, 
535211L), .rows = list(1:6, 7:10)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what your ideal output is, but here's a possible solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(bankAcctID) %>%
  mutate(dummy = date - lag(date)) %>%
  mutate(diff = ifelse(dummy == lag(dummy), dummy/2, NA))
```

The `dummy` variable is included to illustrate the logic, you can remove it by adding the line `%>% select(-dummy)`